# Can PSP Batteries be recharged via USB?

Tags: hardware, psp

I've obtained a recharging cable for my PSP that has a USB plug at the end rather than an AC adapter.

I have a Lithium Ion Battery Pack which i use to charge up my iPhone when it's low on power and I have a bunch of those wall plugs you get with Apple devices that allow a USB cable to be plugged in.

I'm wondering if I can use this USB charge cable on my battery pack and the wall charger without any damage to the battery of the PSP system?

Note: The PSP I'm mainly talking about is my First Gen PSP but I also have a PSP 2000.

Comment: 90% sure you can not charge the PSP-3000 (Fat one) with USB cable. But It has been awhile so I'll leave this as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the first gen can do it but all others should be able to. There is a setting in the Settings menu for USB Charge, so first you need to make sure that's on. Not sure on the effects on battery life, but it should be the same as any other forms of charging.

Answer (score 2):

I have a PSP 2000, and I have a USB charger for it and it works just fine, has for years. I do not know about the first gen but I don't see a reason why it wouldn't. There may be affects I do not see or notice, but my battery life is as long and full as it ever was.

Comment: do you have to have the PSP on to change the usb charge settings or can you do it from the pc?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/129434/psp-2000-turned-off-and-ive-tried-charging-it-with-the-usb-into-my-pc-help-pleas   =     there

Answer (score 2):

From memory you are able to charge it when you have a firmware update. I don't remember which firmware allowed that functionality. You never know unless you try it.