# How to enable PSP 2000's USB charge setting via my PC?

Tags: psp

I received a 2nd generation PSP from my friend. He insists it works but from what I've seen, it doesn't. I've [read that you have to have a certain "USB charge setting"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/115871/4797) -  but can I access that from my PC or only from the PSP?

Comment: I've never owned a PSP of any sort so its alot different to use then a gameboy or ds

Comment: Welcome to the ArQAde! Please take a minute to read the [about](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/about) page to learn how this site differs from a usual forum (e.g. by voting and not posting new questions as "answers" as you already learned the unpleasant way) - also, you get another shiny badge ;) We appreciate the usage of proper English (though if it's not your primary language we'll try to help you there)

Comment: On some motherboards you have certain USB ports that provide additional power. Regarding your question, if you are using a Windows PC, I'm pretty sure there is no "charge setting" anywhere for USB ports.

Answer (score 4):

The "USB Charge" setting they refer to is a setting on the PSP itself. Go to Settings -> System Settings and there should be a USB Charge: On/Off toggle. Set that to On.

Once that's enabled, there's two other conditions you need to meet to charge the PSP over a USB connection:

- It must be plugged into a USB port that provides enough power to charge from; most modern computers won't have a problem with this, as long as the computer is on.
- The PSP must be in USB mode, the same as if you were transferring files to or from it.

Note that this means you can't charge it via USB and play games at the same time.

The official Sony documentation for USB charging can be found [here](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/psp/current/settings/usbcharge.html).